# Influxdb authentication fail using Ruby

Tags: ruby, influxdb

I am trying connect to influxdb using `influxdb-ruby` gem.

with:

```
influx -username admin -password secret 
> SHOW DATABASES;
name: databases
---------------
name
_internal
metrics
```

works fine.

But if I try with Ruby:

```
client = InfluxDB::Client.new(host: "host", port: 8086, database: "metrics", user:"admin", password: "secret")
client.list_databases
InfluxDB::AuthenticationError: {"error":"authorization failed"}
```

Any tip here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you remove `host: "host"` ?

Comment: hi @SteveTurczyn same result. I try host: with localhost and IP of server also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must replace the `user` argument by `username`.

```
client = InfluxDB::Client.new(host: "host", port: 8086, database: "metrics", username:"admin", password: "secret")
```